# How to find the proper ports to be used in core and mapred files during the Hadoop installation on mac OSX?

Tags: hadoop

I recently shifted from Windows to Mac OS, and I am trying to install Hadoop on Mac OSX 10.7 Lion.

In the `core-site.xml` file, I have to add a property:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
</property>
```

and in `mapred-site.xml`:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:8021</value>
</property>
```

I tried to do:

```
$telnet localhost 8020
```

and

```
$telnet localhost 8021
```

but I think both of them are not open on my machine.

`telnet localhost` is working fine but `telnet localhost 8020/8021` is throwing the error:

```
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
Trying fe80::1%lo0...
telnet: connect to address fe80::1%lo0: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Also, I am not able to telnet to my machine's IP address. I get this error:

```
Trying 192.168.0.145...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.0.145: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Operation timed out
```

To find the ports available, I tried running command:

```
$lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
```

but every time I run this command, I'll get different set of IPV6 ports.

I am not sure how to find the proper ports to specify in those two files? Please suggest some pointers on this.

I ran the start-all.sh script and type **jps**, it's not showing the namenode pid

'3049 SecondaryNameNode
3181 TaskTracker
2971 DataNode
3190 Jps
3105 JobTracker'

Answer (score 0):

If you know the process IDs of your name node (you should be able to find this with the `jps` or `ps axww` commands), you should be able to use the output of `lsof -i -P` and filter by the process ID. There should be an option to limit the output of lsof to just a given pid (i know with netstat, an alternative to lsof, you can do this, but the mac version doesn't seem to have the pid output option).

Once you find the pid of the name node process, run `lsof -i -P | grep $pid` and paste that output back into your original question (edit the question, don't post it as a comment or an answer), and we'll go from there.